# Text appear irregularly in UI Table

Tags: uitableview, ios7, swift2, xcode7

was trying to work on my little App of weather forecast by city name !
but i had a problem about irregularly overlapped while iOS simulator was running .

i had checked inspector panel and constrains that i've set up. But nothing works so far !

[image]

and my codes as below :
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var cityEnter: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func findingWeather(sender: AnyObject) {
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Paris/forecasts/latest")!

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let urlContent = data{

            let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            let webSiteArray = webContent?.componentsSeparatedByString("3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:</b><span class=\"read-more-small\"><span class=\"read-more-content\"> <span class=\"phrase\">")

            if webSiteArray?.count > 0 {

            let weatherArray = webSiteArray![1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>")

                if weatherArray.count > 0 {

                let weatherSummary = weatherArray[0]

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ () -> Void in

                     self.resultLabel.text = weatherSummary

                })



                }

            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout ? Is this problem is in all version or specially in iPhone6 Plus

Comment: Yes. i did . I haven't try another version yet but i think it's something irrelevant. do you think it happens because that background PNG Photo that i've used was converted from JPG ?

Comment: No @Akira .. its due to the Autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

As far as know about this issue it is due the Extra `16px` margin taken by `IPHONE 6 PLUS` you have to disable that extra margin.(both leading and trainling)

Navigate to Inspector Area where all your constrain Listed:

[image]

First `Double Click` On Leading Horizontal Constraint then you will get following screen Click on `SuperView-Leading`:

[image]

**Uncheck the Relative to Margin**

[image]

After this their is no way to go back just click anywhere on screen or select any other control then repeat this same for `Trailing Constraint`.

I hope this will help

Comment: Hi Rahui , thanks you for your kindness but unfortunately it doesn't work either .  It might need to redo ..... which i don't really want to .....